# Is there a way to query a VB Script Array?

Tags: sql, arrays, vbscript

I'd like to be able to query an array (multi and single dimensional ) with something like SQL.  Is there a way to do this?

It just seems extraordinarily wasteful to step through it one record at a time.

Comment: Perhaps an array is the wrong data structure to be using. What is your use case?

Comment: thanks...see comment to Dana's answer below for more info.

Comment: A disconnected recordset might suit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268648/how-do-i-sort-arrays-using-vbscript/308735#308735

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  Do you wasteful in terms of having to write the loop, or performance wise?  I'd expect heaping a layer of abstraction over the array would hinder performance.

If you need to search your arrays in something other than linear time (ie., one at a time), you'll need to organize them so that you can so a binary search over them (or any number of other algorithms).

Comment: Rats....I come from a DB background and arrays look so much like a db that I was hoping there was something out there.

Answer (score 2):

A disconnected recordset might suit: [How do I sort arrays using vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268648/how-do-i-sort-arrays-using-vbscript/308735#308735)