# Sorting Dictionary of Strings and Numbers

Tags: sorting, dictionary, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a dictionary object that needs to be sorted, but the keys are date values in the form

```
['Apr. 2013','May 2013','Feb. 2013',
'Mar. 2013','Jul. 2013','Aug. 2013',
'Sep. 2013','Oct. 2013','Jun. 2013','Nov. 2013']
```

As you can see, the dates are out of order. The corresponding value to each key is a number. I want to sort them in chronological order. However, since the months are string values, and since months are not alphabetically in order, I cannot just sort them automatically. Also, though not shown in the code sample, there may be years that are not 2013 as well. How would I go about sorting this dictionary?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want to sort a dictionary by its values? or by its keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13758037/603855):

```
  Const csSep = "|"
  Const cnMax = 100

  Dim sInp : sInp = "Apr. 2013|May. 2013|Apr. 2014|Feb. 2013|Apr. 2011|Mar. 2013|Jul. 2013|Aug. 2013"
  Dim aInp : aInp = Split(sInp, csSep) ' YourDic.Keys
  WScript.Echo "A:", vbCrLf & Join(aInp, vbCrLf)
  WScript.Echo "---------------------"

  Dim oNAL : Set oNAL = CreateObject( "System.Collections.ArrayList" )
  Dim oSB  : Set oSB  = CreateObject( "System.Text.StringBuilder" )
  Dim sWord
  For Each sWord In aInp
      Dim dtCmp : dtCmp = CDate(sWord) ' depends on regional/locale settings
      oSB.AppendFormat_3 "{0:yyyy-MM}{1}{2}", dtCmp, csSep, sWord
      sWord = oSB.ToString()
      oSB.Length = 0
      oNAL.Add sWord
  Next
  oNAL.Sort

  ReDim aOut(oNAL.Count - 1)
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To UBound(aOut)
      aOut(i) = Split(oNAL(i), csSep)(1)
  Next
  WScript.Echo "B:", vbCrLf & Join(aOut, vbCrLf)
```

output:

```
A:
Apr. 2013
May. 2013
Apr. 2014
Feb. 2013
Apr. 2011
Mar. 2013
Jul. 2013
Aug. 2013
---------------------
B:
Apr. 2011
Feb. 2013
Mar. 2013
Apr. 2013
May. 2013
Jul. 2013
Aug. 2013
Apr. 2014
```

The theory is (c) R. L. Schwartz (see [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)).

**Update wrt Martha's answer (and my caveat):**

Don't have to much confidence in VBScript's date conversions:

```
>> WScript.Echo CDate("Dez 2013")
>>
Error Number:       13  ' <-- can't read german
Error Description:  Type mismatch

>> WScript.Echo CDate("Dec 2013") ' <-- can read english
>>
01.12.2013 ' <-- can write german

>> WScript.Echo DateValue("Dez 2013")
>>
Error Number:       13 ' <-- DateValue isn't more intelligent
Error Description:  Type mismatch
```

Comment: I admit I've never had to use VBScript for any language other than English.

Answer (score 1):

The [`DateValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we249285%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function is pretty smart about recognizing dates, no matter how crazily they're formatted. It certainly has no trouble recognizing "Apr. 2013" as 4/1/2013. So in your sort routine, instead of comparing the keys, compare their DateValues.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace each key with the respective formula:

```
newKey = year * monthRank
```

`monthRank` would be 1 for January, 2 for February and so on. `newKey` could then be used to sort every value. Of course this implys that you would have to parse the old keys in order to identify the `monthRank` and `year`, but converting the data from an unstructured data format to a sturctured one includes a cost you have to pay.

Hope I helped!