# Test sorting through QTP

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

There is a java table in my application which has 1 column & 5 rows. Contents of rows are as below. These contents are arranged in descending order

```
172-18-zfs   
MKTLAB  
NFSVOL                                                                
datastore1                       
datastore1(1)
```

after clicking on column header it get sort in asceding order & order is like this

```
datastore1(1)  
datastore1   
NFSVOL  
MKTLAB  
172-18-zfs
```

Through QTP i want to check whether this sortig is correct or not. 
I have used sort() method of dictionary but it doesnt give expected result. It just sort according to alphabatical order.
In expected sorting order 1st priority should be to small letter then to capital letter then to number.

Answer (score 0):

If the built-in sort routine of Scripting.Dictionary does not match the sort routine expected by your application, you may have to create your own that exhibits the logic you want.  Research any VBScript-based sorting option and you may find one that matches or something that will work for you.  A quick search revealed [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268648/how-do-i-sort-arrays-using-vbscript) with several options.