# MS Access: dictionary sorting and manipulation

Tags: vba, ms-access

Suppose I want to have a list of item as below

```
arr["john"] = 40
arr["mark"] = 12
arr["clark"] = 53
arr["sam"] = 23
```

Now I want to sort them depending on the values as below

```
arr["clark"] = 53
arr["john"] = 40
arr["sam"] = 23
arr["mark"] = 12
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There is not a lot of difference between VBA and VBScript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268648/how-do-i-sort-arrays-using-vbscript

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Dictionary from the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime library*:

[Dictionary in VBA](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html)

[Sorting a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808104/sorting-a-dictionary-by-key-in-vba)