# Sorting the data in a loop using ASP Classic?

Tags: asp-classic

I want to sort the data by the `SuppCodeArry` in a loop. This is my code:

```
<%
SuppCodeArry="SA^SA^SB^SA^SC^SB^SA^"
ITEMArry="A^B^C^D^E^F^G^"


    str_SuppCode        = Split(SuppCodeArry,"^")
    str_ItemCode        = Split(ITEMArry,"^")
    SUPPCODE            = ""
    str_SuppCode_NEW    = ""
    str_ItemCode_NEW    = ""
    For a=0 To UBound(str_SuppCode)-1
        Response.Write   str_SuppCode(a) & " ["&str_ItemCode(a)&"] <br>"   

        str_SuppCode_NEW = str_SuppCode_NEW & str_SuppCode(a) &"^"
        str_ItemCode_NEW = str_ItemCode_NEW & str_ItemCode(a) &"^"

    Next    

%>
```

The result I get with this code is:

```
SA [A]
SA [B]
SB [C]
SA [D]
SC [E]
SB [F]
SA [G]
```

I would like to have the result by grouping by the `SuppCodeArry` as below. How do I do this?

```
SA [A]
SA [B]
SA [D]
SA [G] 
SB [C]
SB [F]
SC [E]
```

Thanks for any info on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort arrays using vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268648/how-do-i-sort-arrays-using-vbscript)

Comment: It’s not grouping the data that is problem, its sorting the results.